# How to get luis.ai model as json

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I'm currently wading through some of Microsoft's open-sourced packages for Luis.ai. I'm particularly looking at their [botbuilder](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/LUIS) package.

This package has a model generator which can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/LUISGen).

The generator takes the JSON of the Luis.ai model you've built, the problem I'm having is finding that JSON.

Is there somewhere I can grab the JSON model so I can paste it into this generator?

Answer (score 3):

This is how to use LuisGen (the model generator you have linked):

1. Clone the LuisGen. Make sure you have .Net 2.1 SDK installed. Open "tools.sln" inside packages folder with Visual studio and build it. Now go to "Tools" > "Nuget Package Manager" > "Package Manager Console". It will open at the bottom, type and enter "dotnet tool install -g LUISGen" It will install LUISGen which you will need to use in step 3
2. To get the JSON file it's somewhat hidden. Go to the Luis.ai. There are two ways, either

   - Go To "My Apps" at the top, select tickbox for the app you need then "Export" then "Export as JSON".
   - other way is "Manage" Tab next to Build. Then "Version", then again you need to select the checkbox (for a version) then export > export as JSON.
3. Go to the location of the JSON file. Hold Shift and right click, select "Open PowerShell Here". Now type "LUISGen {Name-of-json-file}.json -cs {Desired-Name-for-CS-file}" without quotes and replace braces with the json file name and the filename you want for the C# Model file

Answer (score 0):

You create your model at [LUIS.ai](https://luis.ai/home). Once your model has been constructed, trained, and published you can export it locally whereby you can use it via CLI in other projects/tools, such as LUISGen. As it states, LUISGen "generates source code from an exported LUIS model".

Alternatively, you can use the LUIS cli (which you referenced/linked) to construct your model, if using command lines is more your thing.

Hope of help!